how to build a vae without reshape error?
I build a VAE following https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/03/variational-autoencoders-with.html
PROBLEM: I thick the problem is in the decoder when I want to reshape the latent Distribution i face this ERROR:
Input to reshape is a tensor with 512 values, but the requested shape has 3200
[[{{node model/sequential_12/module_wrapper_10/independent_bernoulli_7/IndependentBernoulli/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7497]
My CODE:

`encoded_size = 10
input_shape = (10,10,1)

prior = tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=tf.zeros(encoded_size), scale=1),
                        reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)


def get_encoder(input_shape):

    layer = tfk.Sequential([
        tfkl.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters=32, activation='swish', padding='VALID', input_shape=input_shape),
        tfkl.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

        tfkl.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters=64, activation='swish', padding='VALID', input_shape=input_shape),
        tfkl.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

        tfkl.Flatten(),
        tfkl.Dense(tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(encoded_size),
               activation=None),
        tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL(
        encoded_size,
        activity_regularizer=tfpl.KLDivergenceRegularizer(prior)),
])

    return layer




def get_decoder(input_shape):

    layer = tfk.Sequential([
        tfkl.InputLayer(input_shape=[encoded_size]),
        tfkl.Reshape([1, 1, encoded_size]),

        tfkl.Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(2, 2), filters=64, strides=(2, 2), activation='swish', padding='VALID'),
        tfkl.Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(2, 2), filters=32, strides=(2, 2), activation='swish', padding='VALID'),
        
        tfkl.Flatten(),
        tfpl.IndependentBernoulli(input_shape, tfd.Bernoulli.logits),
])

    return layer



encoder = get_encoder((10,10,1))
decoder = get_decoder((10,10,1))
vae = tfk.Model(inputs=encoder.inputs,
                outputs=decoder(encoder.outputs[0]))
vae.summary()



def nll(y_true, y_pred):
    return -y_pred.log_prob(y_true)



vae.compile(optimizer= tfk.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
            loss= nll)
history = vae.fit(X_train,X_train,
            epochs=15,
            validation_data= (X_val,X_val))`


Hi @mmd,You have to change the decoder in terms of understanding the shape of the data after the reshape operation and the following layers: A very important step is to find out the right shape of the tensor before applying any reshaping. It depends upon the output size that you want and the convolution and also make sure that the required Conv2DTranspose layers are oriented in such a way that the required shape of the output is achieved.
